# How to create list of t and name it in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, loops, generics, dynamic, user-input

I have a textbox where the user can enter a number. Based on that number, the same amount of List(Of T) should be created!

How can I dynamically create Lists using List(Of T) and giving each List(Of T) a certain name so I can access them later on?

```
For i = 0 to (txtLoopNumber.Text)

    Dim ThisIsAList As New List(Of String)()

Next
```

For instance, the user enters "3" in the txtLoopNumber. So the loop above should be three times. How can I make the code so that it creates "ThisIsAList1", "ThisIsAList2", "ThisIsAList3"?

**My ideas on solving this problem**

Since I cannot assign a name or a tag I was thinking about creating listboxes where I got the property "name"???? But this doesn't seem like the most effective solution to me

Comment: Store *them* in a `List(of List(of String))` so that `List(0)` is what you would call `ThisIsList0` (or 1).  Not for Nothing but you should go back and accept some of the answers you have been given in the past.  Then, start upvoting answers you find which work.  These acknowledge the help you get and help others find good answers.  See also: [Tour]

Comment: Thanks plutonix. I learnt my lesson and did what you said! Can you also maybe hint me to the direction where you got that List(of List(Of String)) idea? Where can I learn about those things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @**Plutonix** said, you can better achieve this by the indexer of a `List(Of List(Of T)`:

```
Dim lists As New List(Of List(Of String))
Dim amount As Integer = CInt(txtLoopNumber.Text)

For i As Integer = 0 To (amount - 1)
    lists.Add(New List(Of String))
Next i

lists(0).Add("QWERTY1")
lists(1).Add("QWERTY2")

Console.WriteLine(lists(0)(0))
Console.WriteLine(lists(1)(0))
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for the detailed code! Can you also hint me towards the MSDN article/library, where I can look up the nesting lists? I was looking everywhere but didn't know how I can nested them like you did wiht List(Of List(Of STring)) and how to add stuff to them